# C# Converting List<object> to Original Type without an Explicit Cast

Tags: c#, dynamic, generic-list

I'm having trouble converting a list object back to its original type without an explicit cast.  My intention is to generalize methods so I could pass in different db Types such as Person or Company.  I have no problem getting the values via reflection but I need to convert the actual list back to its original type `List<typeT>` instead of `List<object>` in the method I am passing it to.  I am aware of the following methods:

```
 SomeList.ConvertAll(x => (typeT)x);
 SomeList.Cast<typeT>().ToList();
```

However for these methods I will have to explicitly cast typeT.  I have tried the following:

```
formatted1.ConvertAll(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, typeT));
```

and

```
List<dynamic> newList = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var p in SomeList)
{
   newList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(p, typeT);
}
```

No success thus far.  Maybe I should have another game-plan for generalizing these methods altogether.  right now I'm passing the lists in as follows:

```
public string returnJson(List<object> entity, string someString)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like making `returnJson` generic would resolve most of these problems:

```
public string returnJson<T>(List<T> entity, string someString)
{
}
```

Now `returnJson` can be used generically, like:

```
returnJson<Company>(listOfCompanies, "someString");
```

and

```
returnJson<Person>(listOfPersons, "someOtherString");
```

You can still reflect over the objects, but the list is always a list of the type that you need at compile time. No casting required.

Comment: I have to agree with this one.  You beat me to the punch. :)

Comment: Thanks alot, the generic methods have helped a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use generics, that way the calling function can do what it needs:

```
public string returnJson<T>(List<T> entity, string someString)
{
     //not sure what someString is for or why you need the type for this naming scheme

     JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     return jss.Serialize(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic keyword and reflection to create the list.

```
dynamic newList = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeT));
foreach (var p in SomeList)
{
   newList.Add(p);
}
CallOtherMethodOverloadedForListOfPersonCompanyEtc(newList)
```